# Asking for help with E(X(E(Y|X))

Tags: probability-distributions

This is problem 6.9 in Ross.

I have the joint pdf $$f(x,y) = 6/7(x^2+xy/2), 0<x<1, 0<y<2$$
marginal pdf $f(x) = (6/7)x(2x+1)$
conditional pdf $$f(y|x) = f(x,y)/f(x) = (x+y/2)/(2x+1)$$
conditional expectation $$E(y|x) = (3x+16)/(6(2x+1))$$

Then my professor has $$E(xy) = E(xE(y|x)) = \int_0^1 E(y|x) f(x) dx$$

This is the part I don't understand. I thought $E(xE(y|x))$ would be $$\int_0^1 xE(y|x)dx$$ but instead of the $x$, she has $f(x)$.

However, in another example I have 
$$
E(Y|X) = \frac 12 x.
$$

Then my professor has 
$$
E(XE(Y|X)) = E(\frac 12 x^2)
$$ 
I don't understand why in one case you multiply by $x$ and in the other by $f(x)$

Comment: thanks for editing. i wasn't sure how to use mathematical notation

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1):

I would distinguish between capital $X$ and $Y$ and lower-case $x$ and $y$, the former being the random variables, and the latter being the variables used in expressions like $f(x,y)$ and in $\int\cdots\cdots\,dx$, etc.

Then we have
$$
E(X E(Y\mid X)) = \int_0^1 x E(Y\mid X=x) \, f(x) \, dx.
$$

More generally, for any function $g$,
$$
E(g(X)) = \int_0^1 g(x) f(x) \, dx.
$$

Throughout, you should carefully note where I've put capital $X$ and $Y$, and where I've put lower-case $x$ and $y$.

---

**begin quote**

However, in another example I have 
$$
E(Y|X) = \frac 12 x.
$$

Then my professor has 
$$
E(XE(Y|X)) = E(\frac 12 x^2)
$$ 
I don't understand why in one case you multiply by $x$ and in the other by $f(x)$

**end quote**

Again, being careful about capital and lower case, I'd write:

However, in another example I have 
$$
E(Y\mid X) = \frac 12 X
$$
(with a capital $X$, since this is a random variable).

$$
E(XE(Y\mid X)) = E\left(\frac 12 X^2\right)
$$

After that, you can write
$$
E\left(\frac 1 2 X^2 \right) = \int_0^1 \left(\frac12 x^2 \right) f(x)\, dx.
$$

Comment: It may be misleading to say the integral limits are 0, 1 in the general case when in fact they are $-\infty$ to $\infty$ w.r.t. the law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: .....perhaps..... The original question said $0\le x\le 1$.

Comment: have a follow up question. I just edited the original post.